# How to work this if condition in form and codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

i am using this condition for check box value in codeigniter i want if $v_d value take go in 3rd condition ,and value $v_v then go in 2nd condition and if avail both value then go 1st condition.

```
            print_r($this->input->post());
            $id =$this->input->post('id');
            $v_v=$this->input->post('d_v');
            $v_d=$this->input->post('d_d');
            if(isset($v_d) && isset($v_v)){
                echo"hwqq";
            }
            elseif(isset($v_v)){
                echo"hello1";
            }
            elseif(isset($v_d)){
                echo"he2";
            }
```

**HTML CODE iS THIS**

```
<form action="<?php base_url()?>index.php/index/home_email_update" method="POST">
 <input  type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
 <h5><?php echo $msg;?></h5>
 <?php if($f['subscription_discount_voucher']== 1){?>
<div class="email"><input type="checkbox"  name="d_v"  value="0" id="textfield"> Unsubscribe from Discount Voucher Emails.</div>
 <?php }else{?> 
<div class="email"><input type="checkbox"  name="d_v"  value="1" id="textfield"> Subscribe from Discount Voucher Emails.</div>
<?php }
if($f['subscribe_daily_deal']==1){ ?>
<div class="email"><input type="checkbox"  name="d_d" value="0" id="textfield"> Unsubscribe from Daily Deal Emails. </div>  
<?php } else{?>
    <div class="email"><input type="checkbox"  name="d_d" value="1" id="textfield"> Subscribe from Daily Deal Emails.   </div>  
<?php }?>
<div class="email_1"><button type="submit" class="submit_new">Change</button></div> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$id =$this->input->post('id');
$v_v=$this->input->post('d_v');
$v_d=$this->input->post('d_d');

if(isset($v_d) && !isset($v_v)){
    echo "hwqq";
}
else if(!isset($v_d) && isset($v_v)){
    echo "hello1"
}
else if(isset($v_d) && isset($v_v)){
    echo "he2";
}
```

Comment: hi friend every time its goes to last condition!

Comment: try with empty instead of isset

Answer (score 0):

Since [`$this->input->post()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/input.html) returns `FALSE` if there aren't any matches in the `$_POST` superglobal, `isset` check is not going to be an appropriate check here.

Instead you could try using `empty`:

```
if(!empty($v_d) && !empty($v_v)){
  echo"hwqq";
}
elseif(!empty($v_v)){
  echo"hello1";
}
elseif(!empty($v_d)){
  echo"he2";
}
```

Please make sure to check [`Return values of empty`](http://www.php.net/empty#refsect1-function.empty-returnvalues) for the list of things considered `empty`.